# Identify capacitor for really old motor?

Tags: capacitor

A friend has acquired a really old table saw / jointer combo that was apparently made in the 1940s/1950s. The motor is a dual shaft arrangement where one side runs the table saw and the other runs the jointer. Attached to the motor is a large capacitor that sealed and painted and has no markings. The capacitor is dead and I'm trying to figure out the best size replacement and whether it was a start or run capacitor. Because of the dual shaft arrangement, I can't see an easy way to get into the motor to see if it's got a start switch and I'm at a loss how to size the replacement capacitor.

A photo of the motor plate is attached.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: Included more pics of the motor, wiring and capacitor. I had to destroy the case to get into it (which I was trying to avoid), and once inside the capacitor has no markings at all on any surface.

Comment: We could use extra pics of the capacitor and any labels on it, and pics of the motor from a wider view. Pics of the wiring harness as well.

Comment: @Sparky256 - added more pics as requested. That is the only label on the motor. I destroyed the capacitor housing to get at it and there are no markings on the cap.

Comment: Honestly, it looks like something you should take out back and shoot. If it was not for the pervasive rust, it might have a chance of running again. If the insides have this kind of rust, you now have a hefty paperweight.

Comment: Measure the capacitance, or is it shorted?

Comment: @DirkBruere its shorted

Comment: It's probably a waxed paper capacitor. We *might* be able to make a guess as to its capacity. What is the rated max voltage of the motor?

Comment: @DirkBruere the name plate says 200-220v, it's in Australia so we are 240v (230v +23/-14 ).